# Android Deep Links

Tags: android, deeplink

In my web page i add :

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="myapp://dp/product/5" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="myAPP" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="xx.xxxx.xxx.v2" />
```

and in my AndroidManifest i added :

```
  <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mywebsite.com" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

When i tap one of my link in a google search it opens my app but the only info i get from getIntent().getData() is the url link.  How can i get the info (content) from inside my app :

```
 <meta property="al:android:url" content="myapp://dp/product/5" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're opening a `mywebsite.com` link, then that is the URL you'll get back from `getData()`. To get the `myapp://` URI, you'd need to have opened a `myapp://` link directly. You need to add another `<intent>` filter with its own `<data>` tag for your `myapp://` scheme. It would likely look something like this:

If you just want to pass through key/value parameter pairs when a deep link is opened, you could consider a free deep link platform like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). This gives you params with every link, which means more flexibility and no need to handle `myapp://` links differently from `http` links. It also works even if the app isn't installed when the link is first opened.